# Modeless dialog box in App store

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

In C#, how can I show modeless dialog box  for a App store application?

My app has multiple views and a long time task. I would like to show the task progress in a modeless box at the top-right corner of the screen.

It is a information box, no interaction with the user and it should not affect to the user. The user must be able to navigate across the views, enter data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup control solves it:

```
var p = new Popup();
p.Child = new MyUserControl();
p.IsOpen = true;
```